# red line en SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Friends that such, I am developing a systems that reads information of an excel and that information keeps it in my database
When I wanted to make a query in my database about a specific field, my query did not generate any records and I saw the following

[image]

When I copy my cell and paste it into the sql server editor I have these red lines appear in the spaces place, but when it comes to consulting my table those lines are invisible

[image]

I do the following

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tabla where nombre like '% %'
```

The space of the like I put it from my keyboard at the time of execution I did not return any record. Then I decided to copy the red line and put it inside my like and I see as follows visually

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tabla where nombre like '% %'
```

Visually is the same but the difference is that at the time of execution I return the record that meets the condition

My question is, does anyone know why these red lines appear in the space place and how to remove them?

Comment: This site is for questions in english. You should post this question in https://es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on spanish SO

Comment: I already wrote it in English

Comment: What do the fields look like in excel and what is the formatting (font,colour) etc